# ContentLength becomes -1 while reading through http request

Tags: java, android

I am reading an **generated xml** output returned from php file in my android app as below

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.abcdefg.com/hijklm/nopqr.php");
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
String contentType = uc.getContentType();
int contentLength = uc.getContentLength();
```

In php file xml is dynamically generated. The problem is the value of **contentLength becomes -1 when size of xml increses**. I have observed that when size of xml increses more than 7kb value of contentLength variable contain -1.

I infer that it may exceeding the limit of header size but not sure. could anyone explain me 
what should I do for reading large xml content ........?

Comment: Does it switch to [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)?

Answer (score 2):

The content length that you see at the client end is what is set in the header at the server end.  If you see `-1` that means there was no `Content-Length` header in the reply.

I expect that the PHP end is trying to set the `Content-Length` automatically.  If the document is less than ~7kb, it is able to hold it all in a buffer, and then send the header with the actual size.  If it is larger than that, the buffer fills up and the output code is forced to send the header without the Content-Length.

There are two possible ways to address this.

- On the client end, you could should ignore the content length if it is reported as `-1`.  That simply means that no `Content-Length` header was set.  You should probably do this even if you fix the other end to always set the header.
- On the server end, there *may be* a way to tell PHP to use a specific value for the content length.

Comment: But the value of Contentlength is very important for me... because I will create an array of byte type on the basis of the contentlength value and execute a loop to read from the inputstream.                `InputStream raw = uc.getInputStream();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
data = new byte[contentLength];
int bytesRead = 0;
int offset = 0;
while ((offset < contentLength) && (!this.isCancelled())) 
{ bytesRead = in.read(data, offset, 1);
 if (bytesRead == -1) break;
 offset += bytesRead;
}
in.close();`

Comment: is there any alternative way to know the size of the content in advance.........?

Comment: No there isn't, apart from modifying the server to send you the size some other way.

Comment: The simple solution is to write the bytes into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Comment: could you give any link (code segment) for writing bytes in ByteArrayOutputStream from an InputStream object .... without knowing the content size in advance ..........?

Comment: I believe that the stream I/O section of the Oracle Java covers this.  Have you done the tutorial yet?

Comment: But you will learn more if you read the tutorial.  You might even find example code in there.  Hint: don't be lazy.